# laravel , getting Auth::user() table name

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

laravel version : 5.0

Im currently making admin login middleware in laravel.

im using laravel default authentication out of its box.
in this state, i have succesfully logged in.

as i know, i can get the user id by doing `Auth::User()->id;`,
 but the problem : i cant find way to retrive the table name;

below this is the result if i execute `dd(Auth::User());`

> as you can see it cointains information #table:"admins"

```
Admin {#177 ▼
  #table: "admins"
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
}
```

---

This is my middleware where i want to check the table name is admin or not :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class AdminMiddleware extends Model{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if(Auth::User()->getTable() == 'admins') //this doesnt work
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

    }

}
```

im trying to look for it from laravel documentation and search in stackoverflow, seems like i get nothin.

Q : what method i need to call from Auth:: to obtain the table name?

if there is better practice dont hesitate to answer.

Comment: why do you want to fetch the table name ?

Comment: i have user table and admin table, i was trying to validate if the login credentials is an admin, am i missing something..? this approach looks dirty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Admin `class` is extending the `Eloquent\Model`, `Admin::getTable()` or `$adminInstance->getTable()` should work.

Comment: thank you for the reply. 
im sorry, i have improved my question for more details...

do you mean my AdminMiddleware class?

cause im trying to get table name from current autheticated user,
not taking from my database

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two separate tables for admin and users put their credentials into the same table and use a second table namely roles which will contain details of the role of the users. If you want table structure and code for the same let me know and I will share it